# Remove a drawn line from canvas

Tags: android, android-canvas

I have done the code for drawing a line through finger on canvas & also achieved
"Undo" kind of functionality. Undo works pretty fine for the lines which doesn't cross each other, but when the lines cross each other & I undo previous line, it affects the another line as well at the "crossed" point, please have a look at the pics

[image: Two Lines crossing each other]

[image: Undo clears some part of another line as well]

for drawing I used this code

```
mPaint = new Paint();
mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
mPaint.setDither(true);
mPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
mPaint.setStrokeWidth(16);
mPaint.setXfermode(null);

//In MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
mPath.reset();
mPath.moveTo(x, y);

// In MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
circlePath.reset();
circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);

// In MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
circlePath.reset();
mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
mPath.reset();

Now from ACTION_DOWN to ACTION_UP i keep track of all the x,y coordinates to use them for undo feature & here's how i Undo

mPaint = new Paint();
mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
mPaint.setDither(true);
mPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
mPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);

// This helps to have undo kind of effect
mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
```

rest code for `ACTION_UP, ACTION_DOWN & ACTION_MOVE` is same. so basically
i just draw another line on same x-y coordinates with

```
mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
```

& that results same as marked in pic with red circle.

So how can I only erase the part of particular line only even though they are having same x-y coordinates, can I just convert the drawn lines to `ImageView` / `Bitmap` after it's drawn so I can remove the `ImageView` it-self & it don't affect the another line?
Or is there any better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't undo a drawing on a `Canvas`. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html):

> Via the Canvas, your drawing is actually performed upon an underlying
>   Bitmap, which is placed into the window.

One approach to solve your issue could be using a backup `Bitmap` to save the state of the current `Bitmap` before drawing on it, for example using a [Memento pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern).

Take a look at [Fast undo/redo for bitmap editor when memory is limited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901430/fast-undo-redo-for-bitmap-editor-when-memory-is-limited) and [Fast undo facility for bitmap editor application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3238025/fast-undo-facility-for-bitmap-editor-application) (the last one targetting iPhone, but the underlying idea is the same)

Another approach less memory consuming could be saving the state of the objects that you want to draw on your canvas and draw them on demand.

Comment: Means after one line is drawn, I need to store the bitmap before ACTION_DOWN happens & in undo, i should set that bitmap again to the whole view or something?

Comment: Yes, you need to store the previous state in some way. Storing a `Bitmap` before every action can be very memory consuming, maybe it's better to store the state of the events and redraw your `Bitmap` on demand.

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure about "Storing the state of events", can you please tell that in brief?

Comment: Imagine that you want to draw a bunch of lines drawn by the user and you want to be able to undo each line separately. You can store your lines using an structure and all draw the lines from the structure into a Bitmap. When the user undos, you remove your line from the structure and redraw the Bitmap completely (cleaning it and redrawing all the lines from the structure again). To hold the different states of your structure you can use a Memento pattern